# how use vuetify data table with custom pagination and computed data

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js, nuxt.js

hi i'm gonna use [Vuetify data table](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables/) in my project, but have 2 problem.
first i have a status column and in my data it is by number from 0 to 5. but on table i wanna show the related text. for example `2` means `success`. how can i do that as in vutify it get the whole data as `items` prop. how can i change status code to text?
also for pagination section, i have my own pagination logic, something like laravel, that i send request for each page. is there any way to use its pagination with mine or i should hide it and code my own ui for it? also if i can use its pagination, how can change the text for pagination (`Rows per page:`  and `1-2 of 2` )?

NOTE: I'm on Nuxt 2.13 and Vuetify 2.3.9

```
<template>
  <v-data-table :headers="tblHeader" :items="items" :sort-by="['date',]" :sort-desc="[false, true]" multi-sort class="elevation-1">
    <template v-slot:item.actions="{ item }">
      <v-btn small class="text_main_color theme__btn__p" @click.prevent="moreDetails(item)">{{lang.more_details}}</v-btn>
    </template>
  </v-data-table>
</template>
<script>
  export default {
    props:['items'],
    data () {
      return {
        items: [
          {
            id: 1,
            customerName: 'Moji',
            invoiceNum: "SP-0001",
            invoiceItems: "2",
            date: 1594261254,
            price: 295,
            status: 1 // on browser is should show pending
          },
          {
            id: 1,
            customerName: 'Moji',
            invoiceNum: "SP-0003",
            invoiceItems: "2",
            date: 1594261254,
            price: 295,
            status: 2 // on browser is should show success
          },
          
        ],
      }
    },
    computed:{
      tblHeader(){
        return [
          { text: this.lang.customer_name, align: 'start', value: 'customerName' },
          { text: this.lang.order_datetime, value: 'date' },
          { text: this.lang.num_of_items, value: 'invoiceItems' },
          { text: this.lang.total, value: 'price' },
          { text: this.lang.invoice_number, value: 'invoiceNum' },
          { text: this.lang.status, value: 'status' },
          { text: this.lang.actions, sortable: false },
        ]
      },
      orders(){

      }
    },
    methods:{
      moreDetails(value){
        this.$emit('details',value)
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

**UPDATE:**
my pagination format is like this:

```
{
  items: [
    ... // data from back end
  ],
  pagination:{
    more: true,
    cursor: 21
  }
}
```

i send the number of items i want to back for example `from 21, i want 20 items`
and the back give me the above json.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For status text you can use following slot element in v-data-table component:

```
<template v-slot:item.status="{ item }">
  <p>{{ resolveText(item.status) }}</p>
</template>
```

And in methods you should declare `resolveText` function:

```
resolveText (status) {
  switch (status) {
    case 0: return 'zero'
    case 1: return 'first'
    default: return 'infinity'
  }
}
```

About pagination.. No ideas right now